# Make Spring Boot JSON enum deserialization strict, so it does not silently convert invalid values into null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, enums, json-deserialization

I am using Java Spring Boot @RestController with an object containing enum fields.
Spring automagically deserializes the JSON to the `MyRequest` object.

```java
@RestController
public class MyController {
    @PostMapping(path = "/operation")
    public ResponseEntity<MyResponse> operation(@Valid @RequestBody MyRequest request) {
        ...
    }
}

public class MyRequest {
    private MyEnum1 field1;
    private MyEnum2 field2;
    private MyEnum3 field3;
    private MyEnum4 field4;
    private MyEnum5 field5;
    private MyEnum6 field6;
    ... // really a lot of various enum fields!
}

public enum MyEnum1 {
    VAL1, VAL2, VAL3;
}
```

The problem is that if the JSON contains completely invalid value of the `enum` field, the deserializer silently converts them to `null`, without any exception.

```js
{
    "field1": "BLAHBLAH",
    ...
}
```

This is user-unfriendly and treacherous.

I know that I may write custom JSON deserializers for each enum, but the solution is cumbersome and non-elegant.

**Is there a way to globally set the JSON enum deserializer to a "strict mode"**, so if the value is invalid it throws an exception? If so, how and where?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That feature should be disabled by default.

But if you want to set it explicitly you can do it like this:

in your properties:

```
spring.jackson.deserialization.read-unknown-enum-values-as-null=false
```

or as an alternative in a configuration class (actually any bean would work, just make sure it happens early):

```
@Autowired
public void configureJackson(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
   objectMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_AS_NULL);
}
```

Because it should actually be like this by default, I am wondering why it is not for you. Do you enable it somewhere? Which Spring Boot version are you using?

Comment: Yes, you were right! I really found a custom configuration in our code base: `featuresToEnable(new Object[]{DeserializationFeature.READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_AS_NULL})`. I was not aware of it. Thanks a lot!